# Execute script at first ssh login

Tags: bash, scripts, ssh

I'm working with a nvidia tegra computer whose clock reset at each shutdown.
As the computer is not always connected to internet, I often need to set the date manually. Since, I'm exclusively connecting to this computer with SSH, I would like to setup a script calling chrony commands which would run only on the first SSH login.

Thanks

Alex

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to run the script on each login and detect if the login is first (after reboot?) for example using some file under `/tmp` (should get cleared after reboot).

You can either create a wrapper for a user shell, or run it from `~/.bashrc`.